# How does subdag and schedule work?

Tags: airflow

I want to structure my DAGs into reusable pieces but I have a hard time understanding how the start date and schedule part work for subdags, and I can't find the information anywhere in the doc either.

Let's say I have a parent DAG that started today and a subdag that starts in a week, will the subdag be run when the parent DAG run or will it wait to run the subdag until the start date condition is met? Similar question goes for schedule, if I have a schedule that a subdag should run only on Monday's but the parent DAG runs everyday, will the subdag be triggered everyday or only on Mondays?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#subdags):

> SubDAGs must have a schedule and be enabled. If the SubDAG’s schedule is set to None or @once, the SubDAG will succeed without having done anything.

What I understood from this is that `SubDagOperator` is implemented as a **BackfillJob** and hence we need to provide `schedule_interval`.

Comment: I’ve read the docs but I don’t think they answers my questions in a good way.